# How do I manage the memory of a command processor in C++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm trying to build a simple command processor in C++ and I'm stuck on a not so easy issue. I have a class (CommandProcessor) that takes a request of some form. This request is transformed into an object (Command) and put onto a queue or started immediately if there is no running command. The Command object is responsible for fullfilling the request. When it's completed, the CommandProcessor is notified so it can starts processing another command. This callback is where my problem lies : the CommandProcessor should delete the Command at this point, however, since the CommandProcessor is notified during the execution of a method in the Command object, the Command object ends up indirectly deleting itself.

I could possibly delay the callback at the end of the method to ensure that nothing gets executed after it, but I feel that this is a bit of a brittle design.

My other solution was to keep a reference to the completed command and delete it when a new request enters the CommandProcessor, but there's 2 problems with that, the first being that I'm basically using memory that may never be deleted and the second is that the Command object contains some resources that needs to be released as soon as possible (e.g.file handler).

I'm probably not the first guy to stumble on this problem so I was wondering if anybody had a better idea.

**Clarifications**
To simplify, we can say that my program is singlethreaded, that is, the CommandProcessor and the Command object are executed on the same thread. However, not much is executed in the command object aside from doing a bunch of async system calls and waiting for the callbacks. In other words, the Command object's Execute method is non-blocking. Also, only one command is executing at a time.

Note also that this is a very "managed" design, i.e. something that would work in a language like C#, since the garbage collector would be responsible for deleting the Command object later in the lifetime of the program.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify how the *control flow* of the `CommandProcessor` and the `Command` currently work?  Who calls who at what time?  Is this a non-threaded program?  The way you described it sounds like a *continuation-passing* program, which doesn't really work in C++.

Comment: Note that it is safe to `delete this;` as long as the remainder of method doesn't use `this` (even implicitly), or more specifically as long as the deleted object is not used after the delete completes. This applies just as well to calling something else that performs the deletion.

Comment: @Rufflewind thanks for reminding me, I've forgot important detail : you can think of the command object as something than manage a bunch of async requests (file loading), which are either executed on another thread or on the main thread later in the program.

Comment: @subb: Are `Command` and `CommandProcessor` on the same or different threads?  If they are different, how you ensure thread-safety during the "completion notification"?

Comment: @cdhowie Yes absolutely. It's just hard to notice since it's done through a callback. Deleting this is a bit risky by itself, adding a level of indirection increase that risk significantly.

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what your code looks like, but if it is using a queuing mechanism of some sort, why not allocate it as a `std::unique_ptr<Command>`. These can then be added to the queue, and simply popping them off the front when they are done will cause the memory to be deallocated (if you need to run multiple things and keep track of the next thing to run, this combined with an atomic (u)int and `std::deque` might work).

Comment: @Rufflewind They are on the same thread. The Command object calls another system for async file loading which is similar to what I'm building here. The difference is that it pools its "file loading commands" for completion instead of using a callback. It's a valid solution but I was trying not to add unecessary (albeit small) processing when I could just use a callback.

Comment: @subb: Since everything is single-threaded, you should probably look into setting up an event loop similar to how `select` or `epoll` work (or use a library, perhaps).  This way you preserve the "calling hierarchy" and avoid having the `Command` call the `CommandProcessor`.

Comment: Please check this link : http://vichargrave.com/multithreaded-work-queue-in-c/

In this example, command dispatcher will delete the command object after executing it.

Comment: @Yuushi Good guess, I'm doing almost exactly this. However, as soon as one Command finishes, the Command Processor starts another from the queue, which deletes the current Command. The callstack look something like this : Command::OnComplete -> CP::OnCommandComplete --> CP::StartNext, which pops a command from the queue and assign it to the current command member variable (a unique_ptr), which trigger the destructor of the currently completing command.

Comment: @subb "I could possibly delay the callback at the end of the method to ensure that nothing gets executed after it, but I feel that this is a bit of a brittle design." Is your discomfort with the fact that ensuring nothing gets exected after is something that the programmer needs to ensure? If that is the brittleness, you can get rid of it by using a scope guard like [Boost.ScopeExit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: @subb: Do you have multiple `Command`s running simultaneously?  How do you achieve that if the `CommandProcessor` and `Command` are all on the same thread?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of the initial post, you have the following stack (due to single threading) :

CommandProcessor->StartCommand(Command1)->..async.. ->Command1.onComplete()->CommandProcessor->StartCommand(command2)-> command1 gets deleted

You would want to prevent Command1 to delete itself , preferably by doing :

CommandProcessor->deleteFinishedCommand

One way to approach this in single threaded implementations is to have keep a pointer to the previously finished commands and call a finishCommand prior to startCommand.

```
 void finishCommand(Command *aCommand)
 {
     if (previouslyFinished!=NULL)
     {
         delete previouslyFinished;
     }
     previouslyFinished=aCommand;
 }
```

The downfall is that this will delay command deletion with 1 command , so you will basically always have a command in the memory.

The most important part here is that Command.OnComplete() needs to close ALL handles from the command.

This isn't very elegant, but it will help avoid your Command deleting itself.

Further improvements would allow you to delete the previously finished command earlyer (like a watcher thread).

Comment: Thanks, I've thought about "soft deleting" the command object and actually free it's memory later. It's indeed not a very elegant design, but it works.